# Can't access to child list from other list with EL and JSF

Tags: jsf, el, nested-lists, uirepeat

I have a list of "listActivite_realise" which contains a list of "activite" and I'm trying to iterate on each "listActivite_realise" to iterate on each "activite" and access to its properties.

I'm trying to do it by EL in a JSF view :

```xhtml
<ui:repeat value="#{documentBean.unDocument.listActivite_realise}" 
   var="activite_realise" rendered="true">
     <ui:repeat value="#{activite_realise.listActivite}"
         var="activite" rendered="true">

            <h:inputText id="intitule_activite" value="#{activite.intitule}"/>
     </ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
```

In the first repeat, I can access to items of my list "listActivite_realise" from var="activite_realise", such as  activite_realise.propertie.

But in my second repeat, the list "listActivite" seems to not bind the var="activite".

I cannot access to activite.propertie.

I looked everything i found on the subject on stack. and google, but it seems that i use the correct EL/JSF syntax to achieve it.

I also tried to use h:DataTable instead of ui:repeat.

Do you know where the problem could come from?

If the problem can be related on parts of code that i did not expose here, please ask me to do.

Thanks in advance.

PS : Sorry for my English, it is not my native language.

EDIT:
There is no error log in the server logs.

The child ui:repeat does not generate HTML inputs.

Netbeans let me autocomplete in the child ui:repeat but it display the wrong properties. It display properties from the list "listActivite_realise" and not the good one "listActivite".

My persistance.xml file drop and create my database.

In the @Postconstruct of the managed Bean "documentbean", I initialize all records that i need. It creates "Document", add some new  "Activite_realise" composed by a list of "Activite", etc.
It is the only managed bean that i use so far.

```
/*


* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controllers;

import facades.UtilisateurFacade;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javabeans.Activite;
import javabeans.Activite_realise;
import javabeans.CV;
import javabeans.Cadre_formation;
import javabeans.Competence;
import javabeans.Contexte_entreprise;
import javabeans.Document;
import javabeans.Engagament_acteurs;
import javabeans.Evaluation_activite;
import javabeans.Formation_interne;
import javabeans.Le_contrat;
import javabeans.ModuleFormation;
import javabeans.Module_formation_vue;
import javabeans.Page_garde;
import javabeans.Plan_formation;
import javabeans.Planing_alternance;
import javabeans.Postes_competences;
import javabeans.Presentation_apprenti;
import javabeans.Presentation_contrat;
import javabeans.Presentation_entreprise;
import javabeans.Previsionnel_missions_4;
import javabeans.Previsionnel_missions_6;
import javabeans.Previsionnel_missions_9;
import javabeans.Reglement_interieur;
import javabeans.Systeme_dinformation;
import javabeans.Utilisateur;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author Skrface
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UtilisateurBean implements Serializable {

    private Utilisateur utilisateur;

    private List<Utilisateur> listUtilisateur;

    @EJB
    private UtilisateurFacade utilisateurFacade;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of UtilisateurBean
     */
    public UtilisateurBean() {
    }

    public UtilisateurBean(Utilisateur utilisateur, List<Utilisateur> listUtilisateur, UtilisateurFacade utilisateurFacade) {
        this.utilisateur = utilisateur;
        this.listUtilisateur = listUtilisateur;
        this.utilisateurFacade = utilisateurFacade;
    }

    public Utilisateur getUtilisateur() {
        return utilisateur;
    }

    public void setUtilisateur(Utilisateur utilisateur) {
        this.utilisateur = utilisateur;
    }

    public List<Utilisateur> getListUtilisateur() {
        return listUtilisateur;
    }

    public void setListUtilisateur(List<Utilisateur> listUtilisateur) {
        this.listUtilisateur = listUtilisateur;
    }

    public UtilisateurFacade getUtilisateurFacade() {
        return utilisateurFacade;
    }

    public void setUtilisateurFacade(UtilisateurFacade utilisateurFacade) {
        this.utilisateurFacade = utilisateurFacade;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        //On crée les pages type formulaire
        Plan_formation plan_formation = new Plan_formation();
        plan_formation.setUrlImage_plan_formation("dsfhdfhgdjj");

        Reglement_interieur reglement_interieur = new Reglement_interieur();
        reglement_interieur.setUrlImage_reglement("sDGsdgdSH");

        Cadre_formation cadre_formation = new Cadre_formation();
        cadre_formation.setDomaine1("Sfsdhsh");

        Formation_interne formation_interne = new Formation_interne();
        formation_interne.setUrlImage_formation_interne("SDGHGfhdgnhd");

        Previsionnel_missions_9 previsionnel_missions_9 = new Previsionnel_missions_9();
        previsionnel_missions_9.setActivite_11("DSgSGD");

        Previsionnel_missions_6 previsionnel_missions_6 = new Previsionnel_missions_6();
        previsionnel_missions_6.setActivite_11("DSgSGD");

        Previsionnel_missions_4 previsionnel_missions_4 = new Previsionnel_missions_4();
        previsionnel_missions_4.setActivite_11("DSgSGD");

        Postes_competences postes_competences = new Postes_competences();
        postes_competences.setConseils_maitre_apprenti("DSGgsgdsfhdfhdf");

        Systeme_dinformation systeme_dinformation = new Systeme_dinformation();
        systeme_dinformation.setCentralisation_interne_externe("qsfqfqge");

        Contexte_entreprise contexte_entreprise = new Contexte_entreprise();
        contexte_entreprise.setHistorique_entreprise("DhfdHdhqjqjsfj");

        Presentation_entreprise presentation_entreprise = new Presentation_entreprise();
        presentation_entreprise.setAdresse("rue des youlahoup");

        CV cv = new CV();
        cv.setUrlImage_cv("sdlkhflsdgf");

        Presentation_apprenti presentation_apprenti = new Presentation_apprenti();
        presentation_apprenti.setAdresse_pero("12 rue des poulpes");

        Planing_alternance plan_alt = new Planing_alternance();
        plan_alt.setUrlImage_planing("sqihfoqgfoq");

        Le_contrat contrat = new Le_contrat();
        contrat.setUrlImage_contrat("www.image.com/image/tralala");

        Engagament_acteurs engagement_acteur = new Engagament_acteurs();
        engagement_acteur.setUrlImage_signature_apprenti("www.google.fr/image/moon");

        Presentation_contrat pres_contrat = new Presentation_contrat();
        pres_contrat.setAdresse_perso("12 rue des grenouilles");

        Page_garde page = new Page_garde();
        page.setNom("prout");

        //On crée le document
        Document doc = new Document();

        //On ajoute aux pages le document
        page.setDocument(doc);
        pres_contrat.setDocument(doc);
        engagement_acteur.setDocument(doc);
        contrat.setDocument(doc);
        plan_alt.setDocument(doc);
        presentation_apprenti.setDocument(doc);
        cv.setDocument(doc);
        presentation_entreprise.setDocument(doc);
        contexte_entreprise.setDocument(doc);
        systeme_dinformation.setDocument(doc);
        postes_competences.setDocument(doc);
        previsionnel_missions_4.setDocument(doc);
        previsionnel_missions_6.setDocument(doc);
        previsionnel_missions_9.setDocument(doc);
        formation_interne.setDocument(doc);
        cadre_formation.setDocument(doc);
        reglement_interieur.setDocument(doc);
        plan_formation.setDocument(doc);

        //On crée l'utilisateur et on lui ajoute le document
        Utilisateur user = new Utilisateur();
        user.setNom("admin");
        user.setPrenom("admin");
        user.setMot_de_passe("admin");

        //On ajoute les pages et l'utilisateur au document
        doc.setPage_garde(page);
        doc.setUtilisateur(user);
        doc.setPresentation_contrat(pres_contrat);
        doc.setEngagement_acteurs(engagement_acteur);
        doc.setLe_contrat(contrat);
        doc.setPlaning_alternance(plan_alt);
        doc.setPresentation_apprenti(presentation_apprenti);
        doc.setCv(cv);
        doc.setPresentation_entreprise(presentation_entreprise);
        doc.setContexte_entreprise(contexte_entreprise);
        doc.setSysteme_dinformation(systeme_dinformation);
        doc.setPostes_competences(postes_competences);
        doc.setPrevisionnel_missions_4(previsionnel_missions_4);
        doc.setPrevisionnel_missions_6(previsionnel_missions_6);
        doc.setPrevisionnel_missions_9(previsionnel_missions_9);
        doc.setFormation_interne(formation_interne);
        doc.setCadre_formation(cadre_formation);
        doc.setReglement_interieur(reglement_interieur);
        doc.setPlan_formation(plan_formation);

        //Ici on crée les pages multiples style activites_realises
        List<Evaluation_activite> lstEvaluation_activite = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Activite_realise> lstActivite_realise = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            Evaluation_activite evaluation_activite = new Evaluation_activite();
            evaluation_activite.setNom_apprenti("Paul");
            evaluation_activite.setDocument(doc);

            Activite_realise activite_realise = new Activite_realise();
            activite_realise.setNom_apprenti("Jack");
            activite_realise.setDocument(doc);

            //Ici on crée les objets activites et competences
            List<Activite> lstActivite = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                Activite activite = new Activite();
                activite.setIntitule("sdggd_" + i);
                activite.setActivite_realise(activite_realise);
                activite.setEvaluation_activite(evaluation_activite);

                Competence competence = new Competence();
                competence.setDescription("sdvsg_" + i);
                competence.setActivite(activite);

                Competence competence1 = new Competence();
                competence1.setDescription("sdgfhjvsg_" + i);
                competence1.setActivite(activite);

                List<Competence> lstCompetence = new ArrayList<Competence>();
                lstCompetence.add(competence);
                lstCompetence.add(competence1);

                activite.setListCompetence(lstCompetence);
                lstActivite.add(activite);
            }

            evaluation_activite.setListActivite(lstActivite);
            evaluation_activite.setListActivite(lstActivite);

            lstEvaluation_activite.add(evaluation_activite);
            lstActivite_realise.add(activite_realise);
        }

        doc.setListActivite_realise(lstActivite_realise);
        doc.setListEvaluation_activite(lstEvaluation_activite);

        //Pages multiples pour les activites à l'école
        List<Module_formation_vue> lstModule_formation_vue = new ArrayList<Module_formation_vue>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Module_formation_vue module_formation_vue = new Module_formation_vue();
            module_formation_vue.setNom_apprenti("sdgsdg");
            module_formation_vue.setDocument(doc);

            //On crée la liste des objets ModuleFormation
            List<ModuleFormation> lstModule_formation = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
            {
                ModuleFormation moduleformation = new ModuleFormation();
                moduleformation.setExperimenter_entreprise("sdgsdg");
                moduleformation.setModule_formation_vue(module_formation_vue);

                lstModule_formation.add(moduleformation);
            }
            module_formation_vue.setListModuleFormation(lstModule_formation);

            lstModule_formation_vue.add(module_formation_vue);
        }

        doc.setListModule_formation_vue(lstModule_formation_vue);

        user.setDocument(doc);

        //On crée l'utilisateur avec son document et toutes ses pages
        utilisateurFacade.create(user);

        List<Utilisateur> lstUser = utilisateurFacade.findAll();
        this.setListUtilisateur(lstUser);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like your syntax is right. Are you getting some error message? The `rendered="true"` parts are totally unecessary.

Comment: Does it generate HTML inputs for elements other than first one (for these which it *seems to not bind var="activite"*)?

Comment: There is no error in the server logs. Yes you right i could remove the rendered parts, i will do.  And it does not generate inputs for the child ui:repeat, it does for the parent one.

Comment: Two things: show the `listActivite_realise` bean code: are you sure there are getters/setters there? Print out the `size` of the `listActivite` list, is there anything in it?

Comment: Indeed my list is empty. However, i manually add "activite" into "listActivite" in the @Postconstruct of my managedBean as i explained it in the EDIT part. Tell my if I am not clear enought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the Nicholas advise, I found out that I was setting the same list twice in my @Postconstruct method and this is why the list where empty and why nothing where displayed.

Thanks to everyone, especially Nicholas and sorry about this very noob's mistake.